# Reactjs Button with dynamic link

Tags: reactjs

I am using the Material-UI React components.

I have a Button that has a Link to a specific page.
When I update my state ( username in the example below ), should I expect the link to change too or do I need to force an update to the href of the button when I  update my state.username ?

```
<Button component={Link} to={`meeting/${this.state.username}`} variant="raised" color="primary">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render method of React Components is being called on every state change as long as you [update the state properly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly).

So, answering your question: **you should expect the link to change too.**

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the state and the link will be updated automatically as the component renders itself on setState

Use this way to update your state rather than updating it directly.

```
this.setState({username:"newUserName"});
```